# How to integrate C# Code with Ofbiz 9?

Tags: c#, .net, ofbiz

I have one C# Application written using .net framework4.0.It is working good.Now i want to integrate this C# code with my OFBIZ 9 version.Is this possible to integrate C# with OFBIZ. In my C# Application, I have forms for user interaction and also business logic for accessing word document(OOXML).for example, Getting particular paragraph in the Word Document depending upon user login. I don't know is this possible to integrate C# with OFBIZ?.

Please anybody having Idea or experience share with me...

I am eagerly waiting for your reply...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this PDF: http://www.opensourcestrategies.com/ofbiz/OFBIZ_SOAP_RMI_Tutorial.pdf

**To summarize**: All the Ofbiz services can be exported to be available to be called from outside Ofbiz using RMI OR SOAP. Attached PDF has some nice examples on this. This way you can call any Ofbiz service from C# or any other platform remotely.

Comment: Alternatively you can use XMLRPC to make a remote call to Ofbiz service.Check here: https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/using-xmlrpc-as-an-alternative-to-soap.html